# how to show some newest item listview?

Tags: android, listview

I created a `listview` that connects to a database. I want to show some of the newest items (maybe 10 newest items) that will add in a random time? How can I accomplish this? This what I have tried:

```
int i = String.valueOf(mKondisiList));
for(i = 0; i<=5 ; i++ ){
  mKondisiList = myDbHelper.getListKondisi();
  adapterKondisi = new ListKondisiAdapter(this, mKondisiList);
  lvKondisi.setAdapter(adapterKondisi);
  Collections.reverse(mKondisiList);
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but, this code block makes no sense.

```
int i = String.valueOf(mKondisiList));
for(i = 0; i<=5 ; i++ ){
  mKondisiList = myDbHelper.getListKondisi();
  adapterKondisi = new ListKondisiAdapter(this, mKondisiList);
  lvKondisi.setAdapter(adapterKondisi);
  Collections.reverse(mKondisiList);
}
```

To explain what you have did;

- you are getting the list from your database
- initializing the list adapter
- setting adapter to list
- then reverse your order of the list (but you are not notifying the adapter)

You are doing this in a loop exactly 5 times.

What you need to do is:

- get your list from database
- then reverse your order of the list
- initialize the list adapter
- set adapter to list

I should look like this:

```
mKondisiList = myDbHelper.getListKondisi();
Collections.reverse(mKondisiList);
adapterKondisi = new ListKondisiAdapter(this, mKondisiList);
lvKondisi.setAdapter(adapterKondisi);
```

If you want to show only limited number of items, you can do something like below:

```
ArrayList<Object> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
fullList = myDbHelper.getListKondisi();
Collections.reverse(fullList);
//Add first 10 item to your mKondisiList
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mKondisiList.add(fullList.get(i));
}
adapterKondisi = new ListKondisiAdapter(this, mKondisiList);
lvKondisi.setAdapter(adapterKondisi);
```